# pandas dataframe click through rate calculation

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, dataframe, time-series

I have a data frame that is of the form

```
                           variantid eventType
date
2016-02-08 14:43:42  variant1    served
2016-02-08 14:43:46  variant1    served
2016-02-08 14:43:47  variant1    served
2016-02-08 14:43:51  variant1    served
2016-02-08 14:43:53  variant1    served
2016-02-08 14:43:54  variant1    served
2016-02-08 14:43:55  variant1    served
2016-02-08 14:43:55  variant2    served
2016-02-08 14:43:56  variant2    served
2016-02-08 14:43:56  variant1    served
```

I have indexed it by the date. I would now like to do a click through rate calculation for each unique value in the `variantid` column. I am very new to pandas and have no idea how to achieve this. If I do a following operation

```
grouped_by_varid=df.groupby(by=[df.variantid,df.index.hour]).count()
```

I get the following dataframe

```
                eventType
variantid
variant1    0           3
            1           3
            3           1
            4           1
            5           4
            6           3
            7           5
            8           9
            9           9
            10         12
            14       5846
            15      26712
            16      25614
            17      19579
            18      14328
            19       2984
            20         39
            21         32
            22         15
            23         12

variant2    0           3
            1           1
            2           4
            3           3
            4           8
            5          14
            6          24
            7          21
            8          27
            9           9
            10          9
            14       4947
            15      21299
            16      19475
            17      13292
            18       9398
            19       2172
            20         66
            21         64
            22         44
            23         12
```

I would like to generate a data frame which calculates and stores the click through rate of each variant per hour (also per minute but I feel that will be a minor change).

Also I have noticed that since the values in the `eventType` column are strings,if I do a sum, it simple concatenates the values, so how would I calculate aggregate statistics per variant using these string `eventType`s.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and aggregate [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html), [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) and last [`rename`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html):

```
print df
                    variantid eventType
date                                   
2016-02-08 14:43:42  variant1    served
2016-02-08 14:43:46  variant1    served
2016-02-08 14:43:47  variant1    served
2016-02-08 14:43:51  variant1    served
2016-02-08 14:43:53  variant1    served
2016-02-08 14:43:54  variant1    served
2016-02-08 14:43:55  variant1    served
2016-02-08 14:43:55  variant2    served
2016-02-08 14:43:56  variant2    served
2016-02-08 14:43:56  variant1    served

print df.groupby(by=[df.variantid,df.index.hour])['eventType'].size()
                               .reset_index(name='count').rename(columns={'level_1':'hours'})
  variantid  hours  count
0  variant1     14      8
1  variant2     14      2

print df.groupby(by=[df.variantid,df.index.minute])['eventType'].size()
                             .reset_index(name='count').rename(columns={'level_1':'minutes'})
  variantid  minutes  count
0  variant1       43      8
1  variant2       43      2
```